# IntegrityError error while saving value of to foreign key in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hey folks i am getting integrity error while saving my views .Please tell me what  i am doing  wrong

Here is my django model

```
class Ruleinfo(models.Model):
    rule = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    From = models.IPAddressField(null=True)
    to = models.IPAddressField(null=True)
    priority = models.ForeignKey('Priority',related_name='pri_no')
    cisp =models.ForeignKey('Priority',related_name = 'CISP_no')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %(self.rule)



class Priority(models.Model):  
    pri =  models.IntegerField(null = True)
    Ruleno = models.ForeignKey('Ruleinfo',related_name = 'ruleno_no')
    CISP = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s ' % (self.priority)
```

My model form is looking like .

```
class RuleInfoForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
        model = Ruleinfo
        fields = ("rule","From","to")
```

here is my views.py

```
def multiwanrule_info(request):
    data = {}
    no_of_isp = MultiWAN.objects.all()
    try:
        form = RuleInfoForm(request.POST)
    except:
        pass
    print "----------------------------printing form"
    print form
    if form.is_valid():
        rl_frm = form.save(commit=False)
        get_priorities = request.POST.getlist('priority')
        get_cisp_info = request.POST.getlist('cisp')
        rule_object = Ruleinfo()
        for get_pri,get_ci in zip(get_priorities,get_cisp_info,):
            pri_object =  Priority.objects.get_or_create(Ruleno = rule_object)
            pri_object.pri = get_pri
            pri_object.CISP = get_ci

        rl_frm.save()

    else:
        form = RuleInfoForm() 
        data['form'] = form  
        data['number_of_isp'] = no_of_isp
    return render_to_response('networking.html',data)
```

I am getting the above error along this

```
networking_priority.Ruleno_id may not be NULL
```

help me out so that i could get back on track .

Comment: ping me for any clarification

Comment: i think you are not getting `rule_object` . it seems `None`

Answer (score 2):

```
rule_object = Ruleinfo()
```

This just instantiates a new model object.  It is not saved or assigned values.  Since it is not saved it does not have an `id` value.

assigning your rule_object values: rule, from, to, priority, and cisp values, should fix your problem.